# Setting up a Pagefile and Partition in Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition, pagefile

I am setting up 18 new machines for our company, and I have instructions from my new boss on setting up a Pagefile and Partition. I have looked at their existing machines to base the new setups off of, but there is no consistency between any 2 machines, which has left me extremely frustrated to say the least.

My instructions are...

1) Set a static pagefile (use recommended value as max/min), set it on SSD if SSD available.

2) Make 3  partitions:
C: is used for OS and install files
D: is used for backups on machines with a SSD. On machines without SSD create a D: partition for pagefile (2*installed RAM for partition size)
E: must be the partition hosting user files

I have never messed with Pagefiles before, and looking at their existing machines is offering no help. My questions are...

---

1) As the machines I am setting up have no SSD (just 2 SATA drives) does it sound like the Pagefile should be setup on the C: (primary) drive or the D:? The instructions are vague so I have no idea.

2) As C: and D: are both Physical drives, does it sound like C: should be partitioned out to create the E: drive or D:?

---

Thanks for any help I can get. I am extremely stressed out under a massive workload right now, and these vague instructions are quite infuriating.

Comment: I find it funny that they only backup machines with SSDs. Meaning they only care about backuping drive failure (the expected lifespan of a SSD is lower although it can still be a good number of years) and not data corruption, accidental erasals, viruses, and plenty of other threats backups are used against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup the 2nd physical drive as drive letter D: and put your page file there. Also partition it for drive letter E: and your user's files.

Drive letter C: will be for your OS and program (installed) files. It will also accumulate years of Windows OS patches.